# How to add constant in to php file

Tags: php, constants

How to add constant in to php file? I need to use link in all fille how and where i need to add it?
I need to use this line:

`$merchantApiUrl = 'https://spectrocoin.com/api/merchant/1'`

where is the best place?

```
<?php
require_once DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/spectrocoin/SCMerchantClient.php';
class ControllerPaymentSpectrocoin extends Controller
{
    var $time = 600;
    public function index()
    {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: define('MERCHANT_API_URL', 'https://spectrocoin.com/api/merchant/1') and use it like this MERCHANT_API_URL

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
define('CONST', 'http://...');
```

which can be used everywhere like

```
echo CONST;
```

or create a constant in some class that is available in all files. For example:

```
class SCMerchantClient {
   const URL = 'http://...';

}
```

and then in controller

```
public function index()
{
   echo SCMerchantClient::URL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define constants in config file if you have or at the top of the file.

Constants are defined using `define` method as follows:

```
define('MERCHANTAPIURL', 'https://spectrocoin.com/api/merchant/1');
```

Then in your code you can use it like this:

```
MERCHANTAPIURL
```

[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place is config file.

if this link has changed, you don't need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
SCMerchantClient.php
```

Define constant like this:-

```
define('MERCHANT_API_URL', 'spectrocoin.com/api/merchant/1')
```

and if you want to use it in ControllerPaymentSpectrocoin, the write something like :-

```
echo MERCHANT_API_URL;
```